# Updating the result returned by find() method alone in Node.js using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am a newbie to Node.js. My Node.js application has a model called Selfie.

```
# model/selfie.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    selfieSchema = new Schema({
        path: { type: String },
        caption: { type: String },
        sent_mod: { type: Number, default: -1 }, // -1 not sent, 0 sent, 1 accepted
        display_count: { type: Number, default: -1 }, // -1 not sent, 0 sent, 1 displayed
        time_stamp: { type: Date, default: new Date() }
    }),
    Selfie = mongoose.model('selfie', selfieSchema);

module.exports = Selfie;
```

Am breaking down the problem as follows:

1. Retrieve 20 selfies whose *mod_sent* is -1.
2. Update the *mod_count* of those 20 selfies to 0.

To retrieve 20 selfies am using `find()`, `limit()` and then `exec()` method. Once I have those selfies I can use `forEach()` and `update()` to iterate and update each of their *sent_mod* to 0. But this approach performs update operation 20 times. I think there might be a better way to do it. I read about `findAndUpdate()` from MongoDB documentation and found out that Mongoose has various methods like `findOne()`, `findOneAndUpdate()`. But am unable to find a better way to solve my problem using those methods also.

```
# routes/selfie.js
var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),

    Selfie = require('../models/selfie'),

    mongoose = require('mongoose');

router.get('/moderate', function(req, res) {

        Selfie.find({ sent_mod: -1 }).limit(20).exec(function(err, selfies) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            }
            console.log(selfies);

        });
});


module.exports = router;
```

**EDIT:**

**Solution** (as suggested by [gtsouk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1912919/gtsouk)):

```
# routes/selfie.py
var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),

    Selfie = require('../models/selfie'),

    mongoose = require('mongoose');

router.get('/moderate', function(req, res) {

        Selfie.find({ sent_mod: -1 }).limit(2).exec(function(err, selfies) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            }
            console.log(selfies);
            var selfieIds = selfies.map(function(selfie) {
                return selfie._id;
            });
            console.log(selfieIds);
            Selfie.update({ _id: {  $in: selfieIds } }, { $set: { sent_mod: 0 } }, { multi: true }, function(err, num) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return;
                }
                console.log(num);
            });
        });
});


module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model `update()` method can update multiple documents but doesn't have a limit param (as far as i know). You could try updating only the ids you got from the `find()` operation. Create an array, put the _id of each record you want to update and then update using

```
Selfies.update({_id: {$in: array_with_ids}}, {$set:{mod_count:0}}, {multi: true});
```